# I can only export part of my tables with exp command(Oracle11g)

Tags: oracle, export, dmp

I use command

```
exp SYSTEM/SYSTEM@dbInstance owner=user file=c:\exp.dmp
```

to export my tables.

The result is only 4 tables has been exported.

But when I use sqlplus with this user and use SQL

```
select table_name from user_tables
```

to show the tables of this user, the result is 117.

I don't know the reason why this happened.

Comment: hi, post the result of the export, we need to see the log it produces

Comment: @davegreen100 since i'm using the japanese version oracle, maybe it will be hard for u to read the log. But i can tell you that the last line in the log shows that export end without warning

Comment: @davegreen100 could you please tell me what may cause this problem? I will check the point and feedback the result.

Comment: without seeing the log i would be guessing, maybe a space problem on the server giving you an incomplete export. Check the log for anything which says ERROR or INCOMPLETE

Comment: @davegreen100 solved. The problem is that Oracle11 defaultly won't export empty table. So i use `alter table TABLE_NAME allocate extent;` to allocate empty tables and then i works :). Thx whatever